# Why does VC++ 2012 not support specifying the default value of members of a class in its definition?

Tags: c++, class, struct, initialization, default

```
struct A
{
    int a = 8; // VC++ 2012 rejects this.
};
```

I think the code above is more convenient and more expressive than the legal code as follows:

```
struct A
{
    A();

    int a;
};

A::A()
    : a(8)
{}
```

I believe one of the strongest motivations to add new features into the C++ language is making C++ more expressive.

I just wonder why VC++ 2012 not support this?

Comment: c++11 does support this!

Comment: VC++ 2012 rejects that.

Comment: "Why does VC++2012 not support this?" is a question that noone can answer apart from the people at MS.

Comment: You get what you pay for ... g++ 4.7.2 supports it just fine.

Comment: @xmllmx VS2012 hasn't implemented it yet, gcc does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 supports `Default Member Initialization`.

**§ 12.6.2**

> 9 If a given non-static data member has both a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer and a mem-initializer, the initialization
>   specified by the mem-initializer is performed, and the non-static data
>   member’s brace-or-equal-initializer is ignored. [ Example: Given

```
struct A {
  int i = /* some integer expression with side effects */ ;
  A(int arg) : i(arg) { }
  // ...
};
```

> the A(int) constructor will simply initialize i to the value of arg,
>   and the side effects in i’s brace-or-equalinitializer will not take
>   place. —end example ]

You could initialize member by:

```
struct A
{
    int a = 8; 
    int b{3}; // OR
};
```

If you define constructor to initialize `a,b`, constructor initializer lists override defaults.

`I just wonder why VC++ 2012 not support this?`

VS2012 hasn't implemented it yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** this answers the original question, "why does C++ not support ..."

Actually, since C++11, initialization of non-static data members at the point of declaration is supported:

```
struct A
{
    int a = 8; // perfectly legal C++
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  A a1;
  std::cout << a1.a << "\n";
}
```

Output: 8.

This initializes data member `A::a` to 8, and has the implication that `A` is no longer an aggregate, but it wouldn't be one with the user provided constructor either.

Comment: Could you describe the semantics of that construct?

Comment: VC++ 2012 rejects that. Could you refer me to the page of the C++ spec?

Comment: @xmllmx then you should ask "why does VC++ 2012 not support..."

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Comment: @Robᵩ I added something saying that it means initialization. I hope that makes the semantics clear. Since there are no other cofusing factors in this case (constructors setting `a`), I think it can be left at that.

Comment: Whether A should still be an aggregate is in discussion for C++14.

Comment: @MarcGlisse interesting to know that!